# Facebook Ads Error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

We are using the new Facebok Ads report endpoint.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/adreportstats/

In some days, we are getting a weird error:

```
error: 
{
  message: "(#100) The parameter data_columns is required"
  type: "OAuthException"
  code: 100
}
```

When sending the exact same report on a different range it works.

This is done using async=true since the date range is 24-NOV-2013

If anyone from facebook is looking the report_run_id is 6013557375769.

Anyone encountered this issue?

Comment: I got that error today also, for the first time, also with async=true request.

Comment: Happy i'm not the only one :) hope someone else has an idea

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the `data_columns` to your params when you ask for the report.

You can copy them from the original request you did, and this should solve this.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, again it only started happening today.
Adding the data_columns parameter as Tamar mentioned solved it for me:

```
act_XXXXXXXXXXXX/reportstats?report_run_id=XXXXXXXXXXX&data_columns=["campaign_id","placement","impressions"]
```

Comment: Worked for me as well.. the thing it that it's only required in specific days..oh well. Thanks everyone!